# Mongoose duplicate connections in a clustered express.js app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, node-cluster

I have added clustering to my express.js app, and I've specified 2 workers, in the app I connect to my db via mongoose, but when I run the app, my my mongoose connection (mongoose.connect) runs twice. I have tried putting it in the master cluster, but it won't work in the child cluster, is there any way I can make sure the db connects only once? I am using Throng module for this, and the rough code is below:

```
// Using this module for clustering
throng( { workers: 2, lifetime: Infinity, }, start);


// My express app code goes inside this function
function start() { 
  // Connecting via mongoose
  mongoose.connect('')

  // ....some other code here

 server.listen(port, () => { 
    var host = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' && 'localhost'; var port = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' && process.env.PORT;
    console.log(chalk.cyan(` app listening at http://${host}:${port}`));
 })
}
```

I can't figure out what to do, any help in this would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: why do you only want it to connect once? Do you want you child to have to go through the parent to talk to the DB?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm having the same issue but I'm using throng with my worker code.  It needs to share one connection to mongodb because otherwise it could create multiple copies of the same document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per: https://github.com/hunterloftis/throng#a-complex-example
I've never worked with throng but based on the docs this should be close.

```
throng({master, worker, count: 4})

// This will only be called once
function master() {
  console.log('Started master')

  // Connecting via mongoose
  mongoose.connect('')

  // ....some other code here

  server.listen(port, () => {
    var host = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' && 'localhost';
    var port = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' && process.env.PORT;
    console.log(chalk.cyan(` app listening at http://${host}:${port}`));
  })
  process.on('beforeExit', () => {
    console.log('Master cleanup.')
  })
}

// This will be called four times
function worker(id, disconnect) {
  let exited = false

  console.log(`Started worker ${id}`)
  process.on('SIGTERM', shutdown)
  process.on('SIGINT', shutdown)

  async function shutdown() {
    if (exited) return
    exited = true

    disconnect()
  }
}
```